# jQuery tablesorter starts on wrong page

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, tablesorter

I am using `tablesorter` (http://tablesorter.com/docs/) with it`s AJAX pager functionality. here is the code I use to initialize the plugin:

```
$(".track-grid table.tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
        widthFixed: false,
        cssChildRow: 'infoRow',
        widgets: ['zebra']
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        ajaxUrl : 'analyse/getEvents?page={page}&size=10&totalCount='+totalCount,

        customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
            // get current selection & add it to the url
            return url += '&filter=' + JSON.stringify(filter);
        },
        ajaxProcessing: function(data){
            $('#tablesorter tbody').html(data.result.eventsHtml);
            return [ parseInt(data.result.totalEventsCount) ];
        },
        page: 0,
        processAjaxOnInit: true,
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
        updateArrows: true,
        fixedHeight: false,
        removeRows: false,
        cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
        cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
        cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
        cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
        cssGoto        : '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

        cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
        cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option
        cssDisabled    : 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
        cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row

    });
```

This all works well. The events are initialized (fetched from the backend), and whenever I click to change the page, new events are loaded. However, the page seems to "remember" the last time the user has logged in into his account. For example: if I open the page for the first time the pager starts at page 1 (0) but if I switch a couple of pages and then restart the nodeJS server, restart the browser and everything, whenever I login back to the app the page remains the last one I have set manually. How do I force the pager to always start at the first page? (on page refresh as well) Also, page size is shown to be 25 although I set it in the initialization to be 10. Where am I going wrong with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are actually using the [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), which added the ajax functionality to the pager.

You can find all of the [pager options in this documentation section](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager). What you want to do is set the [`savePages` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#save-pages) to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie for the quick answer! That indeed fixed my problem! I cannot explain to myself how did it fix the "size" problem though. I mean, it is logical that it no longer saves which page I was previously on, but how does that affect the size of the page from 25 to 10? Thanks!

Comment: If you set any of the pager size options with a `selected` attribute, it will override the initial setting.